# Adding fields to User Eloquent ORM model

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I would like to extend the existing User model in Laravel 5.0 to add new columns to the table. How can I do so ?

Comment: Just add the columns in your database. Either manually or with Laravels schema builder (and migrations) like @jszobody suggests

Comment: @justadev if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create [migration](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations) by running command:

```
php artisan make:migration users_disabled_column
```

where `disabled` is name of column you want to add to existed table.

2. Edit new migration with [adding column](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns), here is example:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UsersDisabledColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->boolean('disabled')->default(false);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('disabled');
        });
    }
}
```

3. Execute created migration:

`php artisan migrate`

4. Now you can use new column:

```php
$user = User::find($id);
$user->disabled = false;
$user->save();
```